# What is this rebel pilot's backstory?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, character-identification, a-new-hope, deleted-scenes

Regarding the deleted scene in *Star Wars Episode IV: A New Hope*:

We see Luke reunited with Biggs Darklighter in the Rebel Hangar. A *third pilot* joins the conversation and, at one point, says

> I met your father once when I was just a boy. He was a great pilot. If you've got half the skill he had you'll do alright.

**What is this rebel pilot's backstory?** (For example: Who is he? Under what circumstances did he meet Anakin? etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

His name is Garven Dreis and was Red Leader in the Battle of Yavin.

In terms of Star Wars now "official" canon there is not much out there but he was given extensive backstory in the EU (extended universe)

> Garven "Dave" Dreis was the commander of Red Squadron, and a T-65 X-wing starfighter pilot for the Alliance to Restore the Republic. Hailing from the planet Virujansi in the Inner Rim, Dreis originally served with the Rarefied Air Cavalry, fighting in the Clone Wars that took place from 22 BBY to 19 BBY. **During the Battle of Virujansi, Dreis had the opportunity to fly alongside the "Hero With No Fear," Anakin Skywalker.** In the wake of the Clone Wars and the subsequent Declaration of a New Order, Dreis joined the Rebel Alliance—an organization dedicated to shaking the Galactic Empire's hold on the galaxy—after seeing the Empire commit atrocities on his homeworld.

For more details as to his "Legends" / non-canon backstory - this is probably the best place to go:
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Garven_Dreis

Regarding 'non-canon' or "Legends" status - Disney / LucasFilm Story Group have stated that the EU is no longer an official source of information. The only official canon is comprised of all films, tv shows (Clone Wars / Rebels) and new books and comics

http://www.starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised the Clone Wars show never incorporated this character, given the shows penchant for incorporating things that were mentioned in passing in the films.

Comment: Yes, it does seem like a lost opportunity, however, since the scene in question was a deleted scene and thus not officially part of the lore as shown in the films, it may have raised more questions that is solved